# Using setter through decorators RecursionError

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was looking at some link about Python.
https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/python-101-object-oriented-programming-part-1-7d5d06833f26

And there are decorators used in there to create(?) properties and a setter method for it. Below is the code:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, number_of_wheels, type_of_tank, seating_capacity, maximum_velocity):
        self.number_of_wheels = number_of_wheels
        self.type_of_tank = type_of_tank
        self.seating_capacity = seating_capacity
        self.maximum_velocity = maximum_velocity

    @property
    def number_of_wheels(self):
        return self.number_of_wheels

    @number_of_wheels.setter
    def number_of_wheels(self, number):
        self.number_of_wheels = number
```

And this is the usage from the link as well.

```
tesla_model_s = Vehicle(4, 'electric', 5, 250)
print(tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels) # 4
tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels = 2 # setting number of wheels to 2
print(tesla_model_s.number_of_wheels) # 2
```

So, I was trying to understand why should I use it, instead of, you know, directly accessing class variable itself. I tried to run the code but I got `RecursionError`.

```
  File "C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Python/tryit.py", line 16, in number_of_wheels
    self.number_of_wheels = number
  [Previous line repeated 491 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Finally my question is, how can this code work(what is wrong with it maybe?) and more importantly why should I use setter instead of accessing class variable directly?

ps. Any pointers like links to read or keywords for search are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property and attribute should not have the same name, otherwise, the setters and getters will keep calling themselves over and over. Conventionally, you would prepend a leading underscore to *privatize* (though it's not private) the attribute you're creating a property for.

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, number_of_wheels, type_of_tank, seating_capacity, maximum_velocity):
        self._number_of_wheels = number_of_wheels
        ...

    @property
    def number_of_wheels(self):
        return self._number_of_wheels

    @number_of_wheels.setter
    def number_of_wheels(self, number):
        self._number_of_wheels = number
```

Also remember to subclass `object` in Python 2, to make your class work with `property`.